# Improve my routes join/disjoin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rest, refactoring, routes

I have a lot of join/disjoin routes, how could I improve the way I wrote this ?
Or could I make it RESTful ?

```
  match 'events/:id/join' => 'events#join', :as => 'join_event'
  match 'events/:id/disjoin' => 'events#disjoin', :as => 'disjoin_event'

  match 'assos/:id/join' => 'assos#join', :as => 'join_asso'
  match 'assos/:id/disjoin' => 'assos#disjoin', :as => 'disjoin_asso'

  match 'projects/:id/join' => 'projects#join', :as => 'join_project'
  match 'projects/:id/disjoin' => 'projects#disjoin', :as => 'disjoin_project'

  match 'roles/:id/join' => 'roles#join', :as => 'join_role'
  match 'roles/:id/disjoin/:user_id' => 'roles#disjoin', :as => 'disjoin_role'

  match 'groups/:id/join' => 'groups#join', :as => 'join_group'
  match 'groups/:id/disjoin/:user_id' => 'groups#disjoin', :as => 'disjoin_group'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason that this route doesn't seem RESTful is because you're organizing things in terms of *actions*, rather than *resources*. When you're setting up RESTful routes for an application, think about what resources you're operating on, and then limit yourself to the core actions defined by HTTP verbs for those actions.

To take one example, one way of expressing "join a group" might be to have a `membership` resource as a nested route on that group. Then you can perform different operations on that resource, such as `POST` for *creating* a membership (joining a group), and `DELETE` for *removing* a membership ("disjoining" a group). Your routes can be set up like this:

```
resources :events do
  resources :members, :only => [:create, :destroy]
end
```

Then you could make a call to join a group by `POST`ing to `/events/1/members`, and disjoin by sending `DELETE` to `/events/1/members/(membership_id)`

Comment: Ah, nice, I have those join model (events_users, ... etc), I just have to write the controllers, then I could write the routes with ressources ! Thanks.